# Define ArrayType in CSV sample Spark

Tags: csv, apache-spark

I need to define a test sample with ArrayType for Spark to read this data.
Here is how the schema of data looks like:

```
 |-- data: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- stat: float (nullable = true)
 |-- naming: string (nullable = true)
```

My current definition of data field shows null values for all rows so how can I define structurally this data in a CSV file?

Here is how my CSV files structure looks like now:

```
"data1_id","data1_stat","data2_id","data2_stat","data3_id","data3_stat","naming"
"1","0.76","2","0.55","3","0.16","Default1"
"1","0.2","2","0.41","3","0.89","Default2"
"1","0.96","2","0.12","3","0.4","Default3"
"1","0.28","2","0.15","3","0.31","Default4"
"1","0.84","2","0.41","3","0.15","Default5"
```

When I call show on input dataframe I get this result:

```
+-------+-----------+
|data   |naming     |                                                                                  
+-------+-----------+
|null   |Default1   |
|null   |Default2   |
|null   |Default3   |
|null   |Default4   |
|null   |Default5   |
+-------+-----------+
```

Expected result:

```
+----------------------------+-----------+
|data                        |naming     |                                                                                  
+----------------------------+-----------+
|[[1,0.76],[2,0.55],[3,0.16]]|Default1   |
|[[1,0.2],[2,0.41],[3,0.89]] |Default2   |
|[[1,0.96],[2,0.12],[3,0.4]] |Default3   |
|[[1,0.28],[2,0.15],[3,0.31]]|Default4   |
|[[1,0.84],[2,0.41],[3,0.15]]|Default5   |
+----------------------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to transform data & Construct expressions like `array(struct(<add your columns>))`

```
scala> df.show(false)
+--------+----------+--------+----------+--------+----------+--------+
|data1_id|data1_stat|data2_id|data2_stat|data3_id|data3_stat|naming  |
+--------+----------+--------+----------+--------+----------+--------+
|1       |0.76      |2       |0.55      |3       |0.16      |Default1|
|1       |0.2       |2       |0.41      |3       |0.89      |Default2|
|1       |0.96      |2       |0.12      |3       |0.4       |Default3|
|1       |0.28      |2       |0.15      |3       |0.31      |Default4|
|1       |0.84      |2       |0.41      |3       |0.15      |Default5|
+--------+----------+--------+----------+--------+----------+--------+
```

Extracting required columns for array

```
scala> val arrayColumns = df
            .columns
            .filter(_.contains("data"))
            .map(_.split("_")(0))
            .distinct
            .map(c => struct(col(s"${c}_id").as("id"),col(s"${c}_stat").as("stat")))

scala> val colExpr = array(arrayColumns:_*).as("data")
```

Applying **colExpr** expression to DataFrame.

```
scala> val finalDf = df.select(colExpr,$"naming")
```

Schema

```
scala> finalDf.printSchema
root
 |-- data: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- stat: string (nullable = true)
 |-- naming: string (nullable = true)
```

Result

```
scala> finalDf.show(false)
+------------------------------+--------+
|data                          |naming  |
+------------------------------+--------+
|[[1,0.76], [2,0.55], [3,0.16]]|Default1|
|[[1,0.2], [2,0.41], [3,0.89]] |Default2|
|[[1,0.96], [2,0.12], [3,0.4]] |Default3|
|[[1,0.28], [2,0.15], [3,0.31]]|Default4|
|[[1,0.84], [2,0.41], [3,0.15]]|Default5|
+------------------------------+--------+
```